# Convert hours format to minutes (float) with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm following one tutorial for web scraping an I'm stuck with one part.
 I'm only getting errors when I try to run the following code:

```
df7['Time2'] =  df7['Time'].str.split(':').apply(lambda x: float(x[0]) * 60 + float(x[1]) + float(x[2])/60)
```

Get the error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Also tried the following:

```
time_mins = []
for i in time_list:
    h, m, s = i.split(':')
    math = (int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s))/60
    time_mins.append(math)
```

Again didn't work.

My cell is like:

[image: The format of current cell HH:MM:SS]

The result that I want is like:

[image: Objective output]

Any help would be helpful...
Tks in adv.

Comment: please share a textual example of your data frame, also what are the dtypes of the columns is it a timedelta or string?

Comment: `pd.to_timedelta(df7['Time]).dt.total_seconds()`?

Comment: Probably not all your cells have the format: HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data['Time2'] = data['Time'].apply(lambda x: sum([a*b for a,b in zip(list(map(int,x.split(':')))[::-1],[1/60,1,60])]))
```

If you have date['Time'] dtype as string if not then just make small change in above line :

```
x.str.split(':')
```

Comment: Hey Yugandhar. thanks for help,
Almost worked.. but for few minutes only it didn't work:
cell with **43:46** brings value of **2626.000000**.
you are correct, my cells are in str.
when I type info() brings ['Time'] as object

Answer (score 1):

Create Sample Dataframe:

```
# Import packages
import pandas as pd
# Create sample dataframe 
time = ['1:38:17','1:38:31','1:38:32']
gender = ['M','F','M']
data = pd.DataFrame({
        'Time':time,
        'Gender':gender
        })

data
Out[]: 
      Time Gender
0  1:38:17      M
1  1:38:31      F
2  1:38:32      M
```

Convert column into timedelta format:

```
# Time conversion
data['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['Time']) 
# Time in days 
data = data.assign(Time_in_days = [x.days for x in data['Time']])
# Time in hour
data = data.assign(Time_in_hour = [(x.seconds)/(60.0*60.0) for x in data['Time']] )
# Time in minutes 
data = data.assign(Time_in_minutes = [(x.seconds)/60.0 for x in data['Time']])
# Time in seconds
data = data.assign(Time_in_seconds = [x.seconds * 1.0 for x in data['Time']] )

print(data)

    Time   Gender  Time_in_days  Time_in_hour  Time_in_minutes  Time_in_seconds
0 01:38:17      M             0      1.638056        98.283333           5897.0
1 01:38:31      F             0      1.641944        98.516667           5911.0
2 01:38:32      M             0      1.642222        98.533333           5912.0
```

Comment: Thanks Sayali,
When I try to run the time conversion I get the error **expected hh:mm:ss format**.
in my df it has minutes like 43:00 and then more data like 1:23:20.
I tried other conversions as well, couldn't make it.

Comment: you will have to get time column in one format. Seems like you have two time formats in your column. first is 'MM:SS' and 'HH:MM:SS'. convert 'MM:SS' to 'HH:MM:SS' by appending 0 to hour format. '43:00' will become '00:43:00'. then use any of the above technique to calculate time in hours.